# Prepositions nightmare

Tags: prepositions

I'm writing a research paper and I have this doubt:

My sentence:  The first western infected arrived in the US for treatment in August 2, 2014.

The online corrector marks as wrong the preposition "in August", although before months this is the right preposition...

I've tried to change the sentence into: "In August2, 2014, the first..." and it reports me the same mistake...

Could anyone tell me what is the problem that is in these sentences, I'm really lost int he woods....

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You are specifying the exact date, the 2nd of August, so" arrived on August 2, 2014. Alternatively "arrived in August, 2014. http://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/dates

Comment: +1 for "prepositions nightmare." The comment by @Josh61 is a good answer. The correct form is, "The first western infected arrived in the US for treatment ***on*** August 2, 2014.

Comment: The general rule is that you use _at_ with a time, _on_ with a date, and _in_ with longer periods (month, year, decade).